# Are software solutions such as FHE, PHE, Garbled Circuits used in practice?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, garbled-circuits

Is Fully Homomorphic Encryption or Partially Homomorphic Encryption or Garbled Circuits used in practice? Or is an alternative used instead (I don't mean encryption just for storage here)?

Comment: What do you mean by "in practice?"  There are voting systems that use it, but these are still in research.  [One company](http://enveil.com) is selling homomorphic solutions to certain business problems.  One of the barriers to entry is the difficulty of cryptography to the average mortal, and the paradox of being able to manipulate an integer without knowing its value.